# Managing files and sync scenarios

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I am currently ripping my entire CD collection, thus generating large music files. My scenario is:

- Rip music to add locally and to iPod

  - use Sound Juicer pointed to Music folder
  - Music folder is set up to sync with Ubuntu One,
- Rip music not intended for iPod

  - send to custom destination which is set up to sync with Ubuntu One
- Finally, transfer files in Music folder from Rhythmbox to iPod.

This scenario worked really well until I ran out of space on my laptop and had to transfer ripped files from the Music folder and custom destination to an external hard drive.

When removing files from these folders, they were also removed from Ubuntu One. I re-added them and then stopped the automatic sync. I now add my ripped music to my Ubuntu One folder on my laptop, but need to find a way to allow me to remove music from a folder which is set up to sync on my computer without removing them on Ubuntu One.

I'm not sure if this makes sense, maybe I am coming at this from a wrong angle anyway.

Answer (score 3):

From the control panel on the computer with the small disc you tell `syncdaemon` to no longer sync the folder you need to empty:

[image: Ubuntu One Control Panel “Cloud Folders” tab, with a row highlighted to illustrate the point in the text]

and then you can delete the folder and/or its contents without them being removed from Ubuntu One. If later the situation changes and you decide to re-enable sync, syncdaemon will do a “merge”, which should result in any new files in that folder getting added to the sync, but no deletions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works, but it syncs the (old) files already on Ubuntu One with my laptop again causing it to run out of space :-)

I guess the only solutions is to have more than one Music folder then.

Ah well, it was worth a try, and this feature is actually very handy in other circumstances.

//HP.