# Simple image editor tool to draw a simple box/rectangle in an existing image

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

I need a simple image editor tool to draw a simple box/rectangle in an existing image, and probably write a simple text in it.

A similar but not the same question has been asked here before:
[Simple image editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164473/simple-image-editor)

The problem is that none of the solutions given can draw a simple box in an existing image. Pinta looks good, but this tool always crashes and doesn't help at all.

Others such as Shotwell, GThumb, Shutter don't even have a tool to draw a simple rectangle at all.

I'm looking for a very simple tool that can draw a box on existing image like this.

[image: highlight box on screenshot]

Please do not suggest GIMP, as I'm looking for a very simple tool, probably like Pinta, but not buggy and must be stable.

Comment: See my answer to the linked question using Shutter here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1123740/163331

Comment: I use Pinta, but it has a repeatable crash... but I've found a way around it... after editing an image... DO NOT click SAVE... just click the windows close button... then select SAVE when it asks you. Done.

Comment: @heynnema, thanks but the problem is I can't edit an image at all. Once it loaded, it hang, that's it.

Comment: ALL images, or just a certain type?

Comment: Simple image, let say screenshot from my screen. I need this tool for documentation purpose. `ksnip`'s answer from @DK Bose is the best at the moment

Comment: @Parto, thanks but Shutter is exactly the same as Shotwell, GThumb. @DK Bose's answer for `ksnip` is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're using a GNOME environment, try `gpaint`. It's in the *universe* repository:

[image: gpaint]

If you're using a qt-based system such as Kubuntu or Lubuntu 18.10, try *kolourpaint*. It's in the *universe* repository:

[image: kolourpaint]

If you want something a little advanced, try *ksnip*. Its homepage is [here](https://github.com/ksnip/ksnip).

Various versions and package formats of ksnip are available [from here](https://github.com/ksnip/ksnip/releases) as

- an AppImage. You can see [What is an "AppImage"? How do I install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it) for more on AppImages.
- a .deb and
- a snap package

(You need to expand the ` Assets` section below the relevant release to get the download links.)

[image: ksnip AppImage]

Comment: Thanks @DK Bose, `ksnip` looks like something that I'm looking for. This is the best answer so far. Let me test it first

Comment: Oh, well. This `gpaint` looks like dumb way to go but it actually doesnt even have view scaling.

Comment: I didn't know kolourpaint existed, upvoted +1!

Comment: ksnip is just awesome! - Thanks +1

Comment: Yet another very good alternative is the app `drawing`. Available for most linux distros. Includes rectangles, text, arrows, filled boxes, etc., evertyhing you need to quickly annotate an image.

Answer (score 8):

When I need to edit a picture quickly, I do it through the web. Simply because it starts much faster than any "installed" app I ever tried :/

I use [www.Photopea.com](https://www.Photopea.com). To draw a rectangle, choose a Rectangle tool in the toolbar, set the Stroke to Red (or any other color) and Fill to None.

I think it is better than Pixlr, it doesn't require Flash and supports more input / output formats.

It also has advanced features. If you ever need to do more, it is easier to extend the knowledge of one advanced tool, than to learn 37 new single-purpose tools.

Comment: even better than mine! I'll be using this from now on!

Comment: I'm on Windows so when I need to make quick and simple edits to an image I use Paint. It might be limited in power but it also starts extremely quickly, in about 0.5s ;)

Answer (score 1):

when I want the simplest and the quickest, I personally think "web" not "app I'm going to download and install"

https://www.photopea.com/