# How can I include the cursor in the screenshots created when PrtScr is pressed?

Tags: 19.04, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I want to make it so that when I press the print screen key on my keyboard, it actually includes the cursor. I know that it is calling `gnome-screenshot`, but I can't find any way to change the arguments it is using with it. If anyone knows about this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but other, more advanced screenshot tools like `shutter` have an option to include the cursor or not, and can also do things like delayed screenshots (useful for context menus etc. that would go away when you press a key) or directly edit the resulting image.

Comment: @ByteCommander `gnome-screenshot` also provides delay option.

Comment: @ByteCommander https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=shutter doesn't show shutter for 19.04.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of that, thanks @DKBose . Looks like [it got removed from the repos starting in 18.10 due to outdated dependencies](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/shutter-removed-from-ubuntu-1810-and.html). I hope it will get updated and ported to newer libraries at some point, I really like that tool.

Comment: And the author of the link you provided has a ppa: https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/shutter. For simple annotating of images I use the ksnip appimage: https://askubuntu.com/a/1128568/248158

Answer (score 18):

You can do this with [dconf-editor](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-dconf-editor-on-ubuntu-18-04) but with command line as well. Here are the `gsettings` effecting `gnome-screenshot`:

[image: gnome-screenshot gsettings.png]

Use this command to check current settings:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-screenshot include-pointer
false
```

Use this command to turn on the option:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot include-pointer true
```

Use the same technique for the other `gnome-screenshot` settings.

---

Note you can get a list of all settings with `gsettings list-recursively`. For the screenshot above I used the technique in this answer:

- [Bash one-liner to display ALL `gsettings` in GUI dialog window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017045/bash-one-liner-to-display-all-gsettings-in-gui-dialog-window/1017046#1017046)

And the one-liner code (works with `yad` only) is:

```
gsettings list-recursively | sed 's/  */\n/;s/  */\n/;s/\&/\&amp;/g' | yad --list --title "gsettings" --item-seperator='\n' --width=1800 --height=800 --wrap-width=600 --column=Group --column=Key --column=Setting --no-markup
```

Answer (score 13):

`man gnome-screenshot` tells us that

> ```
>   -p, --include-pointer
>           Include the pointer with the screenshot.
> ```

So you'll need to set up a new keyboard shortcut that incorporates `-p`:

[image]

Note that gnome-screenshot has a variety of options described in `man gnome-screenshot` to

- capture the active window
- capture the whole screen
- capture a selected area
- take a delayed screenshot

You can make your own shortcuts for each of these activities.

Comment: But how would the OP make it so that the PrintScreen key behaviour is modified to include this argument?

Comment: Yes, I'm adding that now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the way I am going to do it is adding new shortcuts from the `+` button at the bottom of the keyboard menu in settings.

Comment: @redstoneguy12 actually https://askubuntu.com/a/1146146/248158 is really elegant!