# Screenshot does not include cursor 18.04

Tags: 18.04, cursor, screenshot, mouse-pointer, gnome-screenshot

I'm using default gnome-screenshot and I enabled include pointer in dconf Editor `/org/gnome/gnome-screenshot/delay` and cursor nowhere to be seen.

I used the terminal to set it and still nothing happened.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot include-pointer true
```

Checked if it worked

```
gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-screenshot include-pointer
true
```

Answer (score 1):

I had use a new keyboard shortcut that uses command `gnome-screenshot -p` based off from this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1146145/986391

Comment: Did that, but pointer not included on popOS 22.04.